# convert multiple rows to columns in Linux using Python or Bash

Tags: python, bash, awk, sed, transpose

I have the input as below

### Input

`Name1  Subject1  Marks
Name1  Subject2  Marks
Name2  Subject1  Marks
Name2  Subject2  Marks`

and want to convert to output as below

### Output

`Name Subject1  Subject2
Name1  Marks  Marks
Name2  Marks  Marks`

Comment: This looks like a job for pandas. More specifically, `pivot`.

Comment: Yes I agree but I have the data in my Server and need to manipulate it there

Comment: Bash 4 solution: https://gist.github.com/altblue/2cd2518f2b32f15e6c9374d62d4bd4fe